# cakephp - Greater the (>) not working

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

i am working on a cakephp 2.x . i want to get the specific field result of a user if the date is greater then the date i specify. but unfortunately the query is not working and i am getting an error

here is the query which i am trying

```
public function getLicense($userid)
{

    return $this->field('license', array(
        'idUser' => $userid,
         'registrationDate >'=>2013-08-20

    ));

}
```

i am not sure whether this query is right because i never used greater then sign before in cakephp. help me to correct the query

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you put quotes on the date correctly?

Comment: Check the executed query. @AgRizzo that's how it worked a long time ago - changed because it effectively permits sql injection, won't work in  2.3.

Comment: sorry it was a typo error.i figure out the problem ..thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You're right, just forgot that date is a string and missing quotes. Closed it in quotes:

```
public function getLicense($userid) {
    return $this->field('license', array(
        'idUser' => $userid,
        'registrationDate >' => "2013-08-20"
    ));
}
```